# Bundle PECL extension in a phar

Tags: php, ncurses, pecl, phar

The PHP [ncurses library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php) is not installed on a normal php installation, you must install it as a [PECL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/ncurses.installation.php)

I would like to bundle it in a php phar app.

Is this possibile and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with cweiske's answer.

I understand why you would be interested in doing this, but the reality is that the pre-requisite of PHP for a .phar means that they will never be a standalone executable.  They are like java .jar files. In each case the relevant runtime environment is required.

The PHP solution suggested is simple:

```
if (!extension_loaded('ncurses')) {
    echo "The ncurses Extension is required.  Use PECL or your system package manager to install it.  See http://php.net/ncurses for more information."
    exit;
}
```

With that said, if my assumption is correct, whatever program you are trying to create using ncurses, is probably better written in a self contained language that can be compiled into an executable (c, c++).

Or at least a language that can handle app packaging in a robust and simple way (python, Ruby, Golang). In particular with so much interest in Golang for cross platform tools like Docker, and with terminal libraries like [termui](https://github.com/gizak/termui), I think you should consider whether PHP is really the right tool for the sort of application you are creating.

Answer (score 1):

PECL packages are written in C, which needs to be compiled for the specific PHP version and operating system (and other variables like ZTS and CPU architecture).

You would need to pack the compiled library for every possible combination of the variables above in your `.phar` file and load the correct one yourself.

While this is certainly doable, it's a huge effort that I'd not invest. Rather check if the extension is loaded and generate a nice error message telling what to do if it isn't.